# Cannot read property 'source' of undefined when trying to add association in queryGenerator.SelectQuery in Sequelize ORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to generate a query using QueryGenerator.selectQuery.

```
let query = models.sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('table', {
    include: [{
        model: models.Users,
        where: {
            deleted: false
        },
        required: true,
        attributes: ['id']
    }],
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            [Op.between]: [o.start, o.end]
        },
        deleted: false
    },
    attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn("COUNT", models.sequelize.col("Table.id")), 'count']]
}, models.Table).slice(0, -1);
```

T‌his is the error I am getting.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined at
>   Object.generateJoin
>   (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1433:30)
>   at Object.generateInclude
>   (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1358:24)
>   at Object.selectQuery
>   (/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:1001:34)

github issue tracker https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8751

Answer (score 8):

Going through with the same errors as you and finally solve the problem.

Because `QueryGenerator` is used internally for `Sequelize`, it doesn't have specific docs about this (unfortunately). We should "parse" the options using object **Model** before we passing the parameter into `selectQuery`.

Based on your query, I think you could do this. Please be aware the codes below are untested and use **es6** style

```
// Import sequelize model library
const Model = require("sequelize/lib/model");

// Separate your query options
const queryOptions = {
    include: [{
        model: models.Users,
        where: {
            deleted: false
        },
        required: true,
        attributes: ['id']
    }],
    where: {
        createdAt: {
            [Op.between]: [o.start, o.end]
        },
        deleted: false
    },
    attributes: [[models.sequelize.fn("COUNT", models.sequelize.col("Table.id")), 'count']]
};

// Parse the queryOptions, this operation would serialize the queryOptions
// and this is the important process about building the query
Model._validateIncludedElements.bind(DB.SuitCase)(queryOptions);

// Execute with serialized options object 
let query = models.sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery('table', queryOptions, models.Table);
```

Hope this may help you.

Comment: I keep getting the error ``Model X is associated to Model Y using an alias.`` But I haven't defined an alias at all. Seems to fire this error for all tables I try to query this way. If I query using the normal interface everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add the following to Aditya Kresna Permana's answer;

**DB.SuitCase** here should be replaced with the model of your top query (Which in the case of the OP would be "**models.Table**".
For people who are familiar with the bind function, this might seem logical (Which is why he might not have added it), but it took me a while to figure out!

Example:

```
Model._validateIncludedElements.bind(models.Table)(queryOptions);
```

Comment: Remember to call `Model._paranoidClause(this.model, options)` to support paranoid tables. Without this statement the queryGenerator produces SQL query without checking paranoid tables.

Answer (score 0):

For future references this worked for me

```
const Model = require('sequelize/lib/model');

const queryInterface = await db.sequelize.getQueryInterface();
const queryGenerator: any = queryInterface.queryGenerator;

Model._validateIncludedElements.bind(models.TableName)(
  queryObject
);
      
const sqlQuery = queryGenerator.selectQuery(
  'table_name',
   queryObject,
   models.TableName
);
```