# sequelize not Include all children if any one matches

Tags: sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I am having three association tables back to back. That means item_level_1 have many item_level_2 and item_level_2 have many item_level_3. I used a search query to find any parent or child having a name containing the search text. That means if I type `abc`, then I need to return all parent or child with full details(parents and children). But in my case, if item_level_3 has `abc` in the name, it returns the parent details, but it just only returns the specific child with `abc` from item_level_3. I need to return all children inside item_level_3 where the same parent.

I am using MySQL database in AWS with node

I checked https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#complex-where-clauses-at-the-top-level and tried different combinations. But not help. I might miss something. But I cannot find it.

```js
exports.searchItems = (body) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let searchText = body.searchText.toLowerCase();
        let limit = body.limit;
        let offset = body.offset;
        
        db.item_level_1.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_1.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.item_level_3.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                ],

                [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("item_level_1.status"), Sequelize.Op.eq, body.status)
                ]
            },
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            distinct: true,
            subQuery: false,
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.item_level_2,
                    as: 'item_level_2',
                    where: {
                        status: body.status
                    },
                    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                    required: true,
                    include: [{
                        model: db.item_level_3,
                        as: 'item_level_3',
                        where: {
                            status: body.status
                        },
                        required: false,
                        attributes: ['id', 'name']
                    }]
                }
        ]
        }).then(result => {
            resolve({ [KEY_STATUS]: 1, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "items listed successfully", [KEY_DATA]: result.rows, [KEY_TOTAL_COUNT]: result.count });
        }).catch(error => {
            reject({ [KEY_STATUS]: 0, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "items list failed", [KEY_ERROR]: error });
        });
    })
}
```

**Expected result**

```json
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Rent items listed successfully",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "this is test parent one",
      "item_level_2": [
        {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "this is second test parent one",
          "item_level_3": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "this is the child description with abc"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 40,
          "name": "this is second test parent two",
          "item_level_3": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "this is the child description with def"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 41,
          "name": "this is second test parent three",
          "item_level_3": {
            "id": 70,
            "name": "this is the child description with ghi"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 1
}
```

**Actual result**

```json
{
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Rent items listed successfully",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 21,
      "name": "this is test parent one",
      "item_level_2": [
        {
          "id": 39,
          "name": "this is second test parent one",
          "item_level_3": {
            "id": 9,
            "name": "this is the child description with abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "totalCount": 1
}
```

**item_level_1 model**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const item_level_1 = sequelize.define("item_level_1", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: STRING },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    item_level_1.associate = function (models) {
        item_level_1.hasMany(models.item_level_2, { as: 'item_level_2' });
    };
    return item_level_1;

}
```

**item_level_2 model**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const item_level_2 = sequelize.define("item_level_2", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: STRING },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 },
        itemLevel2Id: { type: INTEGER },
        itemLevel1Id: { type: INTEGER }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    item_level_2.associate = function (models) {
        item_level_2.belongsTo(models.item_level_3, { as: 'item_level_3', foreignKey: 'itemLevel2Id' });
    };
    return item_level_2;

}
```

**item_level_2 model**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const item_level_3 = sequelize.define("item_level_3", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: STRING },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    return item_level_3;

}
```

Comment: should not it be:
item_level_2.hasMany(item_level_3, {as: 'item_level_3', foreignKey: 'itemLevel3Id'}) ?
I see you include item_level_3 from item_level_2

Comment: @niour the above mentioned association is correct because of the relationship between the table(see the newly added last paragraph in the question). I am getting the correct results if I am not search in level 3. But I need to search in level 3 also. Did I missed anything that you are asking?

Comment: I still don't get it. Maybe you had to right it like: 
item_level_2.belongsTo(models.item_level_3, { as: 'item_level_3 }); and use an thought table.
Or maybe you had to tweak a bit the models. Like using a source key at item_level_3 like: 
item_level_2.belongs(models.item_level_3, { as: 'item_level_3, sourceKey: itemLevel3Id}, ); 

At least we all agree that a subquery should be used. Emma's first approached looked really promising though. If you make any changes to the models please try using that also and tell us your feedback

Comment: @niour Agree.  If OP can change it like 2 hasManys: `item_level_1.hasMany(item_level_2)` and `item_level_2.hasMany(item_level_3)`, first option should work and that is simpler.  However, if I respect OP's original `hasMany` & `belongsTo`, this is technically `belongsToMany` association between `item_level_1` and `item_level_3` through mapping table (`item_level_2`).  `belongsToMany` is useful when I don't have to search mapping table with OR options with other tables.  However, since OP is searching the mapping table, subquery is unavoidable (unless I am unaware of other options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complex scenario and required some workaround. Also, I haven't tested all scenarios, so apologies that it may work for a sample case but not all of your needs. I hope this will give you some directions, though.

Based on the SQL written here, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/140006, you can create 2 JOINs between `item_level_2` and `item_level_3`, 1 for filtering and 1 for fetching all associated records.

```
item_level_2.hasMany(item_level_3, { as: 'item_level_3' });
// This extra association will be used only for filtering.
item_level_2.hasMany(item_level_3, { as: 'filter' });
```

Then,

```js
db.item_level_1.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
             Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_1.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
             Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
             // Use the filter association to filter data.
             Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.filter.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
        ],
        ...
        include: [
            {
                model: db.item_level_2,
                as: 'item_level_2',
                where: {
                    status: body.status
                },
                attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                required: true,
                include: [
                    {
                        model: db.item_level_3,
                        as: 'item_level_3',
                        where: {
                            status: body.status
                        },
                        required: false,
                        attributes: ['id', 'name']  // This should fetch all associated data. 
                    },
                    {
                        model: db.item_level_3,
                        as: 'filter',
                        where: {
                            status: body.status
                        },
                        required: false,
                        attributes: []  // Do not fetch any data from this association. This is only for filtering.
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

This covers a scenario when 1 item is matching from `item_level_3` and there are multiple items that associated with the same `item_level_2`. This won't work if there are multiple `item_level_2` is associated with `item_level_1` and 1 of the `item_level_2` is matching with the `searchText`.

I haven't tested, however, maybe you can do similar thing for `item_level_1` as well if you needed.

=================================================

##### Update:

If the association between `item_level_2` and `item_level_3` is `belongsTo`, above solution won't work.

<s>You'll need `WHERE EXISTS` query for `item_level_3`.</s>
(Omitted the wrong solution.)

=================================================

##### Update2:

Use inline `IN` query for `item_level_3` text matching.

Before making inline query, make sure to escape the dynamic contents that will go into the `Sequelize.literal` later.

> Important Note: Since sequelize.literal inserts arbitrary content without escaping to the query, it deserves very special attention since it may be a source of (major) security vulnerabilities. It should not be used on user-generated content.

ref: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html

```js
const escapedSearchText = sequelize.escape(`%${searchText}%`);
```

First setup inline query options to extract `item_level_1`'s ids where the `searchText` appears in any children (`item_level_3`). To do so, I query only `item_level_2` and `item_level_3` tables and using `GROUP` and `HAVING`.

```js
const inQueryOptions = {
    attributes: ['itemLevel1Id'],  // This attribute name and the one in group could be different for your table.
    include: [{
        attributes: [],
        model: db.item_level_3,
        as: 'item_level_3',
        where: {
            name: {
                [Sequelize.Op.like]: escapedSearchText
            }
        }
    }],
    group: 'itemLevel1Id',
    having: Sequelize.literal('COUNT(*) > 0')
};
```

With grouping with `item_level_1`'s id and filtering with `HAVING`, this will return all `item_level_1`'s id where any of its children at `item_level_3` has the `searchText`.

This is still ONLY searching at `item_level_3`'s name.

Next, translate the options into inline query.

```js
const Model = require("sequelize/lib/model");
// This is required when the inline query has `include` options, this 1 line make sure to serialize the query correctly.
Model._validateIncludedElements.bind(db.item_level_2)(inQueryOptions);
  
// Then, pass the query options to queryGenerator.
// slice(0, -1) is to remove the last ";" as I will use this query inline of the main query.
const inQuery = db.sequelize.getQueryInterface().queryGenerator.selectQuery('item_level_2', inQueryOptions, db.item_level_2).slice(0, -1);
```

The generated `inQuery` looks like this.

```sql
SELECT `item_level_2`.`itemLevel1Id` 
FROM `item_level_2` AS `item_level_2` 
INNER JOIN `item_level_3` AS `item_level_3` 
    ON `item_level_2`.`itemLevel3Id` = `item_level_3`.`id` 
    AND `item_level_3`.`name` LIKE '%def%' 
GROUP BY `itemLevel1Id` 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

Finally, insert this generated query into main query.

```js
db.item_level_1.findAndCountAll({
    subQuery: false,
    distinct: true,
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_1.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
            {
                id: {
                    // This is where I am inserting the inline query.
                    [Op.in]: Sequelize.literal(`(${inQuery})`)
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    include: [{
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        model: db.item_level_2,
        as: 'item_level_2',
        required: true,
        include: [{
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            model: db.item_level_3,
            as: 'item_level_3',
            required: false,
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: I checked the above solution. Unfortunately not worked. Because, my association is opposite. I am using `item_level_2.belongsTo(item_level_3, { as: 'item_level_3', foreignKey: 'itemLevel3Id' });`. Because item_level_2 having a field itemLevel3Id where the id of level 3

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I missed the association details in the question. Could you please take a look at the bottom of the question?

Comment: @KIRANKJ I updated my answer.  As I mentioned above, it won't be as your expected result unless you discard some of the `item_level_2`'s id and name.

Comment: Did you mean, the search is mainly happening in level 1 and level 3?

Comment: Not really. You can search level2 but please take a look at result JSON compare against your expected result.  My result have 3 level2 objects and within each level2, there is 1 level3 object.  This is because mappings within level2 table is unique, you cannot have a single id and name of level2.

Comment: are we missing lv2_1's othe sibling childs?. Because in my expectation, item_level_3 is an array

Comment: Based on `hasMany` and `belongsTo` mapping table, I assume you have each mapping per record (1: lv1-abc, 2: lv1-def, 3: lv1-hij where the left number is id of level2).  But I could be wrong so could you show the model definition for all of lv1, 2, 3 tables?

Comment: Your response is correct. I just wrote the expected json which was different from what I am really getting. I just typed the simplified form in an editor and I wrongly wrote the array for `item_level_2`. So I updated my entire question with real data. Also I tried `Sequelize.literal(`EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "item_level_3" WHERE (lower("name") LIKE '%${searchText}%'))`)`. But getting an empty result with `"totalCount": 0`. When I tried the same in MySQL workbench I can see there is an error related to `EXISTS`. Did I miss anything? Also, I am sorry for my wrong question

Comment: Cool. It could be due to DB difference.  my bad, I didn't ask you which DB you are using.  I was testing with Postgres.  let me try on MySQL.

Comment: Updated for MySQL.

Comment: I checked it. But now I am getting all results irrespective of the search text. That means I am getting all siblings of `abc` which is our requirement works fine. But I am getting all other rows from `item_level_1`

Comment: I just tried `SELECT * FROM item_level_3 where EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM item_level_3 WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%abc%'))` this in MySql workbench and getting all rows from 
 `item_level_3`. So Basically we will get all data

Comment: Ah that's right. SELECT query in `EXISTS` doesn't take care of associations so it is looking for whether the searchText exists ever in a whole level3 table.  This is more complex than I thought. Adding the associations in `EXISTS` could solve it but it will add more complexity. In this case, perhaps `IN` query is easier.  I couldn't avoid using subquery but at least using queryGenerator, I could write it in a single query.  Please take a look again and sorry it is taking so long.

Comment: Thank you. I still have some doubts. In inQueryOptions, I can see `attributes: ['itemLevel1Id']`. But my model does not have such a column or relationship. Can I put just `id'?.Also, In `Model._validateIncludedElements` , from where the `Model` should import

Comment: `itemLevel1Id` or similar column _should_ be generated by Sequelize if you don't have it defined explicitly. Try looking `SELECT * FROM item_level_2` to see what column do you have for foreignKey to item_level_1.  You need to group by item_level_1's id so `id` (item_level_2's) won't be correct.

Forgot to add Model's import.  I added in answer.

Comment: you're right, I put `itemLevel1Id` there itself. Also I replaced `Model._validateIncludedElements` with `db.item_level_3._validateIncludedElements` and it seems worked. I did not import and use `Model`. After that I checked by importing the `Model` too. That time also it worked. Which above method should I follow?  Anyway, Great.... You saved me. That you very much

Comment: could you please let me know which is the correct way as described in the above comment

Comment: I based off from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47652112/cannot-read-property-source-of-undefined-when-trying-to-add-association-in-que but if other syntax works for you, I am not sure which is better, tbh.

Comment: I probably should also mention to make sure to escape the `searchText` which is passed to `Sequelize.literal`. The function doesn't escape, so anything within `literal` should not be dynamic or should be escaped.

Comment: in my case your previous version is working fine. Did I missed anything?

Comment: Please check the "Important Note" in the answer (I included in the answer).  When you use `literal`, you need special care to avoid security vulnerability.

Comment: I am sorry for out of scope question. But could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70668105/how-to-select-parent-item-based-on-the-association-in-sequelize

Comment: Try the first solution in this answer using 2 `hasMany` associations.  Or `IN` query with subquery might be faster.

Comment: In the above example we have 3 hierarchy. But in my latest question it has only two. So I am little bit confused about the `2 hasMany solution`. Did you mean `IN query with sub query` is your final answer for this question OR `noir's` answer?. `Note: the mapping table can contain millions of data`

Comment: I tried escaping. But sequelize.escape not found. So I found that `var SqlString = require('sequelize/lib/sql-string');`, SqlString.escape(). But after including this, it is not searching for level 3 items. So I removed for now

Comment: At least I confirmed the `escape` function exists from v5+.  If you are using Sequelize 5 or greater, you supposed to have the function available.  Make sure you are calling the instance function ((db).sequelize.escape) not static function (Sequelize.escape).  Also pass entire string including "%" to escape function and remove "%" from `[Op:like]`.

Comment: I tried db.sequelize as well as Sequelize. None have the function. So I just googled and got the sqlstring. I write like this SqlString.escape(`%${searchText}%`). No error happened. But if I put anything in the search string our search not returning level 3. I can see the back tick is not visible in the comment. Interpret as hilight.

Comment: you need to export the sequelize instance from mydbfile to make it work with `const db = require('mydbfile');  db.sequelize.escape`.  

You can console.log the escaped string and also the generated query on console to debug further.   if your `searchText` is "abc", you should simply get "%abc%" from the escape function.

Comment: 1) Do we need it only in subquery Or do we need to add it in where conditions wherever search text appears? 2)  The advantage will be anybody cannot inject SQL queries with search text?

Comment: 1) when you have dynamic content in `Sequelize.literal`.  in your case only for item_level_3.  2) correct.  All dynamic SQL has to be escaped to prevent SQL injection and Sequelize does escape for many parts but specifically Sequelize calls out `literal` is where they don't escape.

Comment: unfortunately db.sequelize.escape() not found. But I logged with sql string which is same as mentioned with ABC example above. But the result getting after executing the entire API is not same

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately i think a subquery is unavoidable. You need to find lvl_2 ids first from the matching lvl_3 items.

```
const itemsLevel2 = await db.item_level_2.findAll(
    {           
        attributes: [Sequelize.col("item_level_2.id"), 'id2'],
        where: 
        {[Sequelize.Op.and]: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.item_level_3.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'), 
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("item_level_2.status"), Sequelize.Op.eq, body.status)
        ]},
        include: [{
            model: db.item_level_3,
            as: 'item_level_3',
            where: {
                status: body.status
            },
            required: true,
            attributes: ['name']
        }]
    }
)
ids = itemsLevel2.map(item => item.id);
```

And then use the required ids like that:

```
exports.searchItems = (body) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let searchText = body.searchText.toLowerCase();
        let limit = body.limit;
        let offset = body.offset;
        
        db.item_level_1.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_1.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("item_level_2.name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("item_level_2.id"), Sequelize.Op.in, ids),
                ],

                [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col("item_level_1.status"), Sequelize.Op.eq, body.status)
                ]
            },
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            distinct: true,
            subQuery: false,
            attributes: ['id', 'name'],
            include: [
                {
                    model: db.item_level_2,
                    as: 'item_level_2',
                    where: {
                        status: body.status
                    },
                    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
                    required: true,
                    include: [{
                        model: db.item_level_3,
                        as: 'item_level_3',
                        where: {
                            status: body.status
                        },
                        required: true,
                        attributes: ['id', 'name']
                    }]
                }
        ]
        }).then(result => {
            resolve({ [KEY_STATUS]: 1, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "items listed successfully", [KEY_DATA]: result.rows, [KEY_TOTAL_COUNT]: result.count });
        }).catch(error => {
            reject({ [KEY_STATUS]: 0, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "items list failed", [KEY_ERROR]: error });
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have two points which hopes we don't need a sub query. First is https://sequelize.org/master/manual/eager-loading.html#including-everything. The second is, in my case I have only three levels and we can assume we can use sub query. But in some other cases multiple hierarchy will be a problem. So i can see this is a common scenario. So assumed there is a built in solution. I am very new to Sequelize. So my above assumptions might be wrong or I missed some steps provided in the above link (already tried many steps). Could you please share your thoughts.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I missed the association details in the question. Could you please take a look at the bottom of the question?

Comment: I updated the entire question. Could you please take a look

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.