# How to select parent item based on the association in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I am having an instrument and instrument mapping table. Some of the instruments have entries in the instrument mapping table. In the mapping table, there is the status with true or false. **A single instrument can be repeated multiple times in the mapping table with any random status(true/false). Also some Instruments don't have entry in the mapping table.** I need to fetch below conditions from payload body

1. Fetch all instruments

```json
{
   "instrumentStatus": "",
   "searchText": ""
}
```

2. Fetch all instruments that are only in the instrument mapping table with status as true even if the mapping table contains false entry for that particular instrument.

```json
{
   "instrumentStatus": true,
   "searchText": ""
}
```

3. Fetch all instruments excluding those which are in the instrument mapping table with status true -- **This is the important and complicated one**. The mapping table contains many true and false status with a single instrument. So we need to fetch all instruments that are not present in the mapping table as well as instruments that are not having true status in the mapping table

```json
{
   "instrumentStatus": false,
   "searchText": ""
}
```

**Instrument table**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Instrument = sequelize.define("instrument", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: STRING },
        description: { type: STRING }
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    Instrument.associate = function (models) {
        Instrument.hasMany(models.instrument_map, { as: "InstrumentMap" });
    };
    return Instrument;

}
```

**Instrument mapping table**

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const InstrumentMap = sequelize.define("instrument_map", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        instrumentId: { type: INTEGER },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 1 },

    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    InstrumentMap.associate = function (models) {
        InstrumentMap.belongsTo(models.instrument, { as: "instrument", foreignKey: 'instrumentId' });
    };
    return InstrumentMap;

}
```

**Code to fetch instruments based on the condition**

```js
let condition = [];

if (body.instrumentStatus != null && body.instrumentStatus != "" && body.instrumentStatus) {
    condition.push(Sequelize.where(Sequelize.count("InstrumentMap." + "status"), Sequelize.Op.eq, body.instrumentStatus));
}

db.instrument.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                    [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
                        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("instrument." + "name")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + body.searchText + '%'),
                        Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("instrument." + "description")), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + body.searchText + '%')
                    ],

                    [Sequelize.Op.and]: condition
            },
            order: [
                [Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col("instrument.name" )), "ASC"]
            ],
            offset: body offset,
            limit: lbody.imit,
            distinct: true,
            subQuery: false,
            include: [
            {
                    model: db.instrument_map,
                    as: 'InstrumentMap',
                    attributes: ['status'],
                    required: true,
                }
            ]
            }).then(result =>
```

Comment: Do all instruments have records in InstrumentMapping?

Comment: @Anatoly Payload will be `{"instrumentStatus": true/false/""}`

Comment: I see `require: true` which means yu will get instruments only if they have InstrumentMapping records

Comment: @Anatoly i checked all the combinations. But I might need both based on the payload. What you think?

Comment: Then you need to construct both `where` and `require` options based on the payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Case 1, 2, and 3, what you are fetching is

Case 1: You want to fetch ALL instruments even if there is no instrument_map. => LEFT JOIN.

Case 2: You want only instrument_map with a status == true.  => INNER JOIN

Case 3: You want to fetch ALL instruments even if there is no instrument_map. => LEFT JOIN. However, exclude any instrument which has 1 or more instrument_map with status = true.

```js
// Make sure req.body.status is either true or false. If it is not neither true nor false, status becomes undefined.
const status = [true, false].includes(req.body.status) ? req.body.status : undefined;

// Case 1: no condition.
let statusCond;

// Case 3: Get instrument whose instrument_map does NOT EXISTS with status = true.
if (status === false) {
    statusCond = Sequelize.literal(`NOT EXISTS ( \
        SELECT 1 FROM instrument_map \
        WHERE instrument.id = instrument_map.instrumentId \
            AND status = true)`)

// Case 2: Filter to status = true only
} else if (status === true) {
    statusCond = { '$InsturmentMap.status$': true }
}

db.Instrument.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        [Op.or]: [
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('name')), Op.like, `%${body.searchText}%`),
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col('description')), Op.like, `%${body.searchText}%`),
        ],
        [Op.and]: statusCond
    },
    distinct: true,
    include: [{
        model: db.InstrumentMap,
        as: 'InstrumentMap',
        attributes: ['status'],
        required: status || false,  // Only if req.body.status is true, we need INNER JOIN. Otherwise, LEFT JOIN (required: false)
    }]
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working. I just checked for payload as false first, because it is the most important. While fetching the same, I am getting all instruments. `Note: An instrument have both true and false status in the mapping table. If any true occur in the mapping, we need to skip the instrument even if it have false stauts`. Payload as true working fine

Comment: Ah I see.  I got the definition wrong.  So your Case 3 is "Fetch all instruments where ALL instrument_map status is false or none."?   Case 2 is same?

Comment: Yes, if no entry or all entries with only false status. If any true entry, we need to skip

Comment: How about Case2?   "all entries with true"?     Could you update your definition in the question.  Case 3 is "Fetch all instruments excluding those which HAS 1 or more instrument mappings with status = true"

Comment: Case 2 is any instrument with true in the mapping table should return even if it having false status. For case 3 you are right. I will update the question

Comment: Updated.  I wasn't sure for Case 2 if you want to fetch all instrument_map including status = true OR fetch only instrument_map with status = true.  For now, it does latter, but if it is not correct, let me know.

Comment: I don't want the childs of instrument mapping table. So any result is fine. I will check and let you know the result

Comment: I can see one critical issue with pagination. Even if I add `offset+=limit`, the old list of items is coming in some offsets. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I found out the issue. I need to add `subQuery: false` for running `else if (status === true) {
    statusCond = { '$InsturmentMap.status$': true }
}`. I commented `subQuery: false` and pagination works fine. But `status true` will not works anymore. Could you please share your thoughts.

Comment: I just removed `NOT` from the false condition query and build the status condition for status true. Then it seems working. Thank you. Please share if it break in any condition

Comment: I can see by adding `separate: true` inside include wherever hasMany relation exists. Is that safe? I am little bit confused which is correct way

Comment: The actual issue for the pagination is you need `order`.  Because without `order`, the returned data are not guaranteed to have same ordering every time.  Therefore, if you use `offset&limit`, you have to use `order` to make sure you get same ordered data before segmenting the data. I suggest you undo the latter changes to step back to see first if ordering is corrected or not.  Because taking out NOT doesn't make sense to me (unless I got the definition wrong). I don't think `separate: true` is necessary. `separate: true` is running 2 SQLs instead of 1 SQL. (1 is often better).

Comment: Actually the question is a simplified form of my real code. The real code contains order by name and several AND  and OR statements. Also I found same issue in pagination in another module too with subQuery:false. So I tried there seperate:false and fixed now. Based on the comment do you have any better alternative or suggestions please

Comment: I need to see the actual `order` code to debug, if you want me to take a look further.  If you mean sequelize crashed with "Unknown column" by "pagination issue", then "subQuery: false" makes sense. However, if you mean "ordering is working" by "pagination issue", I suspect there is something else going on other than `subQuery`.

Comment: I updated the code. I googled and I can see several people having the same issue while using subQuery false with pagination, and its a common scenario.

Comment: I see, that is where `separate: true` came from.  Did you say you don't use any data from `instrument_map` besides checking the existence of status = true/false?  If so, you can omit `include` and use only `EXISTS` query and this works fine with pagination.  

this post is getting too long and off topic from the original question, please raise a new question regarding the pagination.

Comment: I have two modules which needed subQuery false. One is the above which don't need the data from instrument mapping table. The other one need data. So after googling I put seperate true. And its works fone. But I was little confused if it is the correct way or not. That's why I asked you for getting an expert opinion

Answer (score 1):

All cases: `require: false`

Case 1: no `where` condition at all

Case 2:

```js
where: {
  '$"InstrumentMap".status$': true
}
```

Case 3:

```js
where: {
   [Op.or]: [
   {
    '$"InstrumentMap".id$': null
   },
   {
    '$"InstrumentMap".status$': false
   }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I created question with minimalistic form. Actually, my where condition contains both `[Sequelize.Op.or]` and `[Sequelize.Op.and]` with so many objects. I just updated my question because I am little confused how I could integrate your solution in my question. I am extremely sorry for that

Comment: also whenever I put the case 2 where, I am getting `"Unknown column 'InstrumentMap.status' in 'where clause'"`

Comment: You can place the whole object with `Op.or` from case 3 to the `condition` array

Comment: about the `unknown column` I edited the answer and added double quotes. Please try that way

Comment: When I put the `Op.or` to condition, then it giving empty. Because the condition never satisfy

Comment: How so? Did you indicate `require: false`? Maybe you need to indicate `subquery: false` on the root level options of a query as well

Comment: I added `subquery: false` in root. In and condition it is checking false condition as well as null condition. So it will not occur. But in query perspective `search OR conditions AND(null check OR false check)` will work. But I don't know if Sequelize having option to add OR condition inside AND without a sub query

Comment: You already have `AND` in `condition`, right? And you just need to add the object `{
   [Op.or]: [ ...` to this array of conditions. It will be converted to `AND ((conditions) OR (condition2) OR ...)`

Comment: I tried it, But If any other false entry there for an instrument even if there is true for that instrument, it will return. In my case even if there is false, the same must not contain true in the mapping table

Comment: Then you need to add a condition with a SQL subquery (SELECT COUNT(*) ...) using Sequelize.literal