# How to get Sequelize ORM generated SQL

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to get generated sql query from model to use it in other queries:

```
const aIds = ModelA.findAll({
    attributes: ['id'],
    where: {
        status: 'active',
    },
});

ModelB.findAll({
    where: {
        aId: {
            [Op.in]: a.toSql, // i need something like this here (select id from a where status = 'active')
        },
    },
});
```

Note: I just want to know that if it is possible to convert ORM to raw sql to use the query in other places.

Comment: Please provide the actual goal of you question to prevent XY Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem.  
If you want to retrieve all records from `ModelB` that has some sort of relation to `ModelA` you can either just put the result of `aIds` into the second query or explicitly establish relations between these two tables

Comment: is ModelA and ModelB associated?  If so, you might be able to achieve what you want with `join`.  If not, does Update2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70574307/2956135 help?

Comment: @AliSherafat Bluntly speaking, no - you can't get query. The closest solution for your topic will be 1) await first `findAll` 2) map `aIds` from array of objects to array of `id` values 3) put this array into next `findAll`, right where you typed `a.toSql`

Comment: @Jaood_xD thanks, but this is not what I expect because array of id can be very big that makes problem for me.

Comment: @AliSherafat Then you have to look at another approaches. I suggest that `modelA` and `modelB` are relatated to each other. My solution would be to establish the association between them. This approach could help you with filtering. More info on this topic you can find here: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/

Comment: You can get SQL from `queryGenerator` but I would suggest to have this as the last option (this is sort of not practical option).  Have you consider JOIN option?  If you can give us a sample data and expected output, we can help identify if you can achieve your goal without/with `queryGenerator`